# How can I validate a Redactor rich text field in a front-end form using the VeeValidate Vue.js plugin?

Tags: redactor, javascript, validation, frontend-form

### Scenario

I'm using the [VeeValidate](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com) [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org) plugin to validate a Craft front-end form that contains a [Redactor](https://imperavi.com/redactor/) rich text field.

### Problem

Validation of the rich text field fails because Redactor adds `style="display: none;"` to `<textarea>` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

Add the [Redactor `Sync` callback function](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/callbacks/sync/#callback-sync) to the Vue.js instance to synchronize code/data between Redactor’s visual layer (UI) and the form’s `<textarea>` element.

As per the Redactor documentation:

> Visual layer contains multiple temporary tags that allow visual editing. Synchronization with textarea inserts clean code to the textarea, removing all temporary tags, styles and attributes.

Solution source: [Validate Redactor WYSIWYG Textarea Field #603](https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/issues/603)

#### Vue.js/VeeValidate Component

```js
// in your component.
export default {
    mounted() {
        var vm = this;
        $('#redactor').redactor({
            callbacks: {
                sync: function () {
                    vm.$validator.validate('fieldName',  this.code.get());
                }
            }   
        });
    }
}
```

#### Vue.js/VeeValidate CDN

```js
<script>
    Vue.use(VeeValidate);

    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        delimiters: ['${', '}'],

        mounted: function() {
            var vm = this;
            $('#redactor').redactor({
                callbacks: {
                    sync: function () {
                        vm.$validator.validate('fieldName',  this.code.get());
                    }
                }   
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```